# What is the meaning of `auto` value in a CSS property.

Tags: css

What is the meaning of `auto` value of a CSS property. What happens when value of a CSS property is set to `auto`?

Comment: The behavior of `auto` in CSS depends on the attribute you are assigning to.  You will have to provide an example of which attribute you are interested in if you would like a more specific answer.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The value of said property is adjusted **automatically** according to the content or the context of the element.

For example, a block-level element with `height: auto` will grow taller as it contains more text. For another example, a block element with `margin: 0 auto` will have the left and right margins increased until it becomes centered along the y-axis of the viewport.

It really depends on the property you give the value to, different properties behave differently depending on the content and context.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa: Nope, even in properties that accept both values auto does not always mean 100%. A 100% width for example forces an inline-block element to be 100% of its container width, even if there are other elements on the same line (those elements get pushed to the next line instead). An auto width causes an inline-block to shrink to fit its contents, which is certainly not 100%.

Comment: Is 'auto' the default value for all? Can every property have the value 'auto'?

Comment: @robsch: No, whether or not a property has auto as a possible value, let alone the initial value, depends entirely on the property. For most properties, an auto value flat-out makes no sense.

Answer (score 16):

auto means automatically adjusted. The most common reason I use auto is:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to center an element.

Please note: if size is not declared, then it won't work.

Example 1: div is not centered, auto does not work

```
<style>
    .cont {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="cont"></div>
```

---

Example 2: div is centered to the page

```
<style>
    .cont {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="cont"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends. Here are some common usages of the `auto` value.

### Height: auto

the element height depend upon the height of its children.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    child content
  </div>
</div>
```

### Width: auto

for block level element the width is the container width subtracted the element's horizontal spacing (margin+border+padding).

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    calculated content width is 200px
  </div>
</div>
```

note that the behaviour is different when the container is flex with align.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  width: auto;
  background: orange;
  /* comment out next line to make width take parent's width */
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

### Margin: auto

center a block level element horizontally.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

push an element to the end inside flex container.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: orange;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.item3 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    child 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    child 2
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    child 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on that attribute you use. For example, a block width set auto will expand full space of its parent element, but a block height set auto will only expand needed space of its content.

```
<style>
    #outer{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border: solid 2px black;
    }
    #inner{
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
</style>
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">content</div>
</div>
```