# How can I center a div within another div?

Tags: html, css

I suppose that the `#container` will be centered within `#main_content`. However, it is not. Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

```css
#main_content {
  top: 160px;
  left: 160px;
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #2185C5;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_content">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to get the `position:relative;`in you `#container`

Comment: what browsers are you testing on? Here's a fiddle with your code and it's working fine on the latest chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/mFwCp/

Comment: Horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: Featured in [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT3GUKuAzIs&t=13s).

Comment: just set container div with `display: flex` and inner div with `margin: auto` and        `position: relative`

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You need to set the `width` of the container (`auto` won't work):

```css
#container {
    width: 640px; /* Can be in percentage also. */
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

The CSS reference by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) explains it all.

Check out these links:

- [auto - CSS reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/auto)
- [margin - CSS reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin)
- [What is the meaning of `auto` value in a CSS property - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471850/what-does-auto-css-property-means)

In action [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sann/xACwL/).

Comment: This is not the solution. It only centers the container horizontally. Not vertically!

Comment: Using flex with `"justify-content: center; align-items: center;"` is another option

Comment: but you have to display: flex; if you want to use the solution mentioned directly above.

Answer (score 55):

Technically, your inner DIV (`#container`) **is** centered horizontally. The reason you can't tell is because with the CSS `width: auto` property the inner DIV is expanding to the same width as its parent.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UZ4AE/

```css
#container {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
```

In this example, I simply set the width of `#container` to `50px` and set the background to `red` so that you can see that it is centered.

I think the real question is "How do I center elements horizontally with CSS?" and the answer is (drum roll please): *it depends!*

I won't do a full rehash of the myriad ways to center things with CSS when W3Schools does it so nicely here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp but the basic idea is that for block level elements you simply specify the desired width and set the left and right margins to `auto`.

```css
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**Please note:** This answer only applies to *block* level elements! To position an *inline* element, you will need to use the `text-align: center` property on the first *block* parent.

Answer (score 49):

Another interesting way: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atuz910p/)

#### CSS

```css
.container {
   background: yellow;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.centered-div {
   width: 80%;
   height: 190px;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 5px;
   background: blue;
   color: white;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="centered-div">
            <b>Enjoy</b>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, avoid defining class="container" or at least be aware that 'container' is a bootstrap css definition

Answer (score 18):

You can center float div with this little code:

```css
#div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the only correct solution. All the other barely center the inner div horizontally. This is how you center the inner div also vertically.
The only correction: 
position: absolute; // not display...

Comment: @PeterMortensen I disagree with this edit; I believe the author meant 'center float' as in simply 'center' a div in a way that floats, rather than centering a div that has `float` properties already assigned. Although more importantly, answers on this question shouldn't be getting edited at all, really.

Answer (score 13):

Try to add

```css
text-align: center;
```

to your parent container CSS declaration. And the following to the child container:

```css
display: inline-block;
```

It must do the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Now just define your

`#main_content` `text-align:center` and **define your** `#container` `display:inline-block;`

as like this:

```css
#main_content {
    text-align: center;
}

#container{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: It should be adding text-align: center to the container and display:inline-block to the child div or the main_content.

Answer (score 6):

Use `margin:0 auto;` to the child div. Then you can center the child div inside the parent div.

Answer (score 5):

I have used the following method in a few projects:

https://jsfiddle.net/u3Ln0hm4/

```css
.cellcenterparent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.cellcentercontent{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would try defining a more specific width, for starters. It's hard to center something that already spans the entire width:

```css
#container {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want as this:

#### HTML

```html
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="container">vertical aligned text<br />some more text here
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
#main_content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #2185C5;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#container{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

#### How?

In a table cell, vertical align with middle will set to vertically centered to the element and `text-align: center;` works as horizontal alignment to the element.

Noticed why is #container is in inline-block because this is in the condition of the row.

Answer (score 4):

It would work giving the `#container div width:80%` (any width less than the main content and have given in %, so that it manages well from both left and right) and giving `margin:0px auto;` *or* `margin:0 auto;` (both work fine).

Answer (score 3):

Try to get the `position:relative;` in your `#container`. Add an exact width to `#container`:

```css
#main_content {
    top: 160px;
    left: 160px;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #2185C5;
    position: relative;
}

#container {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/YpwMh/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

```css
#main_content {
    background-color: #2185C5;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
#main_content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #2185C5;
    position: relative;
}

#container {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Try this. It tested OK. There is a live check [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3njp/).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a new way to easily center your div using Flexbox display.

See this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5u0y5qL2/

Here is the CSS:

```css
.layout-row {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.layout-align-center-center {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone said it, but I guess it won't hurt saying it again.

You need to set the `width` to some value. Here is something simpler to understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/XUxEC/

Answer (score 2):

To make a div in center. There isn't any need to assign the width of the div.

A working demo is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6yukdmwq/

```css
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        display: table;
        border: 1px solid red;
        text-align: center;}

    .center {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .content {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="container">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Helllo Center Text</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your width is set to auto. You have to specify the width for it to be visibly centered.

Your #container spans the whole width of the #main_content. That's why it seems not centered.

Answer (score 1):

Without setting the `width`, it will get the maximum width it can get. So you cannot see that the `div` has centered.

```css
#container
{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;  /* Just to see the different */
}
```

Comment: See the different what?

Answer (score 1):

Make the CSS content this way...

```css
#main_content {
    top: 160px;
    left: 160px;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #2185C5;
    position: relative;
 }

#container {
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

A working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/golchha21/mjT7t/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set a width for `#container`, just add

```css
text-align: center;
```

to `#main_content`.

Comment: This won't work with `position:relative;` - it'll center the content, sure, but not the div itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `width: auto` to a block element, then the width would be 100%. So it really doesn't make much sense to have the `auto` value here. It is really the same for height, because by default any element is set to an automatic height.

So finally your `div#container` is actually centered, but it just occupies the whole width of its parent element. You do the centering right, and you need just to change the width (if needed) to see that it is really centered. If you want to center your #main_content then just apply `margin: 0 auto;` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if this is the output you want:

```html
<div id="main_content" >
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#main_content {
    background-color: #2185C5;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine I think, though you might need to reset "top:200px;" according to your needs:

```css
#main_content {
    top: 160px;
    left: 160px;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #2185C5;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must assign a width to the div you want to center.

Like this:

```css
#container {
    width: 500;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

More information and examples on these links:

- *[CSS Layout - Horizontal & Vertical Align](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)*
- *http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_container*

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#kid {
    width:70%; /* 70% of the parent */
    margin:auto;
    border:2px solid #F00;
    height: 70%;
}
```

This does solve the problem very well (tested in all new browsers), where the parent div has class="parent" and the child div has id="kid".

That style centers both horizontally and vertically. Vertical center can only be done using complicated tricks--or by making the parent div function as a table-cell, which is one of the only elements in HTML that properly supports vertical alignment.

Simply set the height of the kid, margin auto, and middle vertical alignment, and it will work. It's the easiest solution that I know.

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main_content {
  top: 160px;
  left: 160px;
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #2185c5;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```