# css make the text center

Tags: html, css

this is my html

```
<div class="logoArea">
            <img  src="images/oifcoman-logo.jpg"/>
            <div class="titleClass">Call Center Dashboard</div>
        </div>
```

this is my css

```
.logoArea {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.titleClass {
    color: #343434;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Ultra', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 2px white, 0 3px #777;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:red;
    width:40%;
    top:10px;
}
```

This is what the result:
[image]

I want it to be this:
[image]

Comment: [THIS][1] post might be of help, request seems similar.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376634/how-can-i-center-a-div-within-another-div

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to solve this. Here is one with minimal changes to your existing styling.

```
.logoArea img {
    float: left;
}
```

Usually it requires additional changes in the code for actual centering in the parent window, but it seems to go well with the other styles you already have.

**EDIT**

Looking again at the result, I'm having second thoughts. My solution is good only for non-dynamic elements (elements that won't change dynamically but remain the same). Since it appears to be a header and therefore a relatively static element, my solution may still be valid, only with adding a required amount of `padding-top` to the center div. I don't know how much because in your example you used a very large font-size and I have no idea of the size of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Set the image `float:left;` and the text `display:inline-block;` and the `.logoArea` `text-align:center;`.

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/u5W9G/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<div class="logoArea" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
            <img  src="images/oifcoman-logo.jpg"/>
            <div class="titleClass">Call Center Dashboard</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It does't work. this center the text inside the div. not center the div inside the parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS vertical-align:middle if the element is td (not div) or try this trick: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: vertical aligh. does't make any effect in my case

Comment: vertical-align make affect in td elements only (not div).

Comment: in my situation, there is no table

Comment: @chung Vertical-align can be applied to any inline elements that share the same parent...not just `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<div class="logoArea">
            <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3d6S.jpg?s=128&g=1"/>
            <div class="titleClass">Call Center Dashboard</div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.logoArea {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.logoArea img {display:block;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;}
.logoArea .titleClass {float:left;}
```

JavaScript (must include jQuery first)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var h=$('.logoArea').height();var ch=$('.logoArea .titleClass').height();
    var pTop=((h-ch)/2)+'px';
    $('.logoArea .titleClass').css('paddingTop',pTop);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcAjq/