# Centering DIV inside another DIV

Tags: html, css, center

I already tried many of solutions on stackoverflow (`margin:0 auto;` `text-align`, ...) and none of them yet worked.
I'm trying to center navigation menu (div) on the middle of navigation bar, but till now I've been unable to do that. I successfully did it with `margin-left:20%` but what this caused is when I minimized window, button fell beneath others and destroys whole webpage.

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}

header{
 height:2.5vw;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#2f2f2f;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #111111;  /* #888888 */
}
nav{
 /* margin-left:20%;
 margin-right:20%; */
}
li{
 display:flex;
 height:2.5vw;
 width:20%; /* 33.2% 19.9vw */
 float:left;
 border-left-color:#000000;
 border-left-style:solid;
 border-left-width:thin;
 border-right-color:#000000;
 border-right-style:solid;
 border-right-width:thin;
 text-align:center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction:column;
 color:#5F5F5F;
 font-size:1vw;
}
li:hover{
 background-color:#505050;
}
li:first-child{
 border-right:none;
}
li:last-child{
 border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<header><nav><li class=but>Home</li><li class=but>Projects</li><li class=but>Contact</li></nav></header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376634/how-can-i-center-a-div-within-another-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

Make your `<nav>` flexbox like:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}

header{
 height:2.5vw;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#2f2f2f;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #111111;  /* #888888 */
}
nav{
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
li{
 display:flex;
 height:2.5vw;
 width:20%; /* 33.2% 19.9vw */
 float:left;
 border-left-color:#000000;
 border-left-style:solid;
 border-left-width:thin;
 border-right-color:#000000;
 border-right-style:solid;
 border-right-width:thin;
 text-align:center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction:column;
 color:#5F5F5F;
 font-size:1vw;
}
li:hover{
 background-color:#505050;
}
li:first-child{
 border-right:none;
}
li:last-child{
 border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<header><nav><li class=but>Home</li><li class=but>Projects</li><li class=but>Contact</li></nav></header>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @DownbeatTax My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your nav element has a width of 100%, as all block level elements do by default. So there is no room to push up against the sides to center it.

So, you need to give it a `width`. Then, to center it, give it a `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

By making the width, say 50%, that gives your margin room to grow and push up against the sides of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, it explains and gives visual representation which means loads. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just give it a `width` then center it with margin:auto

```
nav{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to work with responsive webs, which means i'd rarely use pixels, since it really depends on devices which resolution they have, so it could look different on various devices. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @DownbeatTax change it with percentage **%**