# How to center instagram image block

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have a look at this test site: https://dev.amberaviationacademy.com.au/testinstagram

I want to center the entire instagram images block to center. e.g. like this:

[image]

Based on this: [How can I center a div within another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376634/how-can-i-center-a-div-within-another-div), what I need to do is the `set margin 0 auto` for the instergram block and `set width: 90%`. Setting percentage is good when we don't resize the browser. Is it a way to set it auto-center, even when the browser resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes: add `text-align: center` to `.content` and add `display: inline-block;` to `a`:

```css
.block-instagram-block .content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center; 
}

a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works? Does it mean if parent element set to text-align center, any inline-block will be centered?

Comment: `text-align: center;` makes all children to be centered inside the parent. children display should be set as `inline-block` to prevent stand each child to new line if it would be `block`. So in parent we center children and `inline-block` children come in one line filling whole width of parent.

Comment: is it working fine? I tried it but not working all the images are aligned center only!

Comment: @user7357089 You have the right to create a new question in SO and to describe your problem details.