# I can't get a div to center horizontally

Tags: html, css

I can't get a div #buttonwrap to center on my site. I have tried every option that is suggested in [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376634/how-can-i-center-a-div-within-another-div). But it still doesn't work. And what is strange is that #backgroundwrap works fine with the same code. I have linted my CSS and HTML markup, but no help.

Hope someone can help me solve this issue, it has been driving me crazy and delete nearly all my code! The full code is online here: http://setup.industries/projects/masqueradeclassix/

```
.buttonwrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/* parent */

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: @praveen this is not a duplicate as mentioned in the post

Comment: Okay, will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> width: 100%;
> margin: 0 auto;
> ```

It's 100% wide, with auto margins.

So the margins are computed to put it in the center.

i.e. 0 on the left and 0 on the right.

It *is* centered.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to have the div be ONLY the width of the ul > li that it contains? How would you go about that?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is what you need. I really wanted you to find out the solution from there, but here you go:

```css
.buttonwrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: I made a really dumb mistake by making the child div also 100%. Feel stupid now :) Thank you anyway Praveen.

Answer (score 1):

If the `width` is 100%, it makes no sense to center the element using `margin: 0 auto;` - it already fills the width of its container. Make the `width` a value smaller than 100%, or a fixed pixel value.

Comment: I made a really dumb mistake by making the child div also 100%. Feel stupid now :) Thank you @Johannes