# Why is Bootstrap nav dropdown menu aligned to the right?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, alignment

I am having a bootstrap dropdown. It works fine, but when I am inside a page accessed through the menu, then it gets weird:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vw49cpP7weo/UZw0Jh_zmhI/AAAAAAAACJc/oadR5CTIus0/s640/dropdown.png

You can see in the picture, the menu is displaced to the right.

I paste the code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="index.html"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Zimil Ltda</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="acerca.html">Quienes somos</a></li>
                <li class="active" class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="jubilados.html">
                        Productos <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="jubilados.html">Préstamos a jubilados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cbu.html">Préstamos CBU</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros.html">Otros créditos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="trabajar.php">Trabajá con nosotros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Just `pull-right dropdown-menu` worked for me.

EDIT:

Deprecated `.pull-right` alignment

As of v3.1.0, we've deprecated `.pull-right` on dropdown menus. To right-align a menu, use `.dropdown-menu-right`. Right-aligned nav components in the navbar use a mixin version of this class to automatically align the menu. To override it, use `.dropdown-menu-left`.

Comment: Good solution! this will add "left:auto" and "right: 0" style and successfully align the div to the right

Answer (score 5):

`.pull-right` has been deprecated as of Bootstrap 3.1.0

use 
`.dropdown-menu-right`

See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment

Answer (score 5):

As tested on version 3.3.2 of bootstrap, **dropdown-menu-right** does not work for me either.  Here's what I did to fix it in my case.

Instead of:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
```

I used:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 0; left: auto;">
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: **dropdown-menu-right** already do this `.dropdown-menu-right{right:0;left:auto}` If this class doesn't work for you, you probably have an error in your CSS or use an old version of BootStrap. As I said, you need to use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or higher.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your css file or as style element this:

```
.dropdown-menu { left:auto; }
```

I had a similar problem with displaced drop-down and this worked for me.....

Comment: To be honest, I'm not absolutely clear on this one. In my case I had the elements of the dropdown arranged horizontally and also displaced. I'm assumming that the setting of 'auto' resets the objects default placement, free of the any ancestor elements attribute settings (I had to add a separate entry to switch the menu entry display from horizontal to vertical). Anyone else know for definite?

Comment: This seems to help explain why:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471850/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-value-in-a-css-property

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
```

to

```
<ul class="nav pull-left">
```

OR just remove the helper class `pull-right` leaving only the `nav` class:

```
<ul class="nav">
```

Here's a JS Bin demo: http://jsbin.com/ezuray/1/

Comment: `pull-left` isn't needed as by default it will be aligned to the left anyway.

Comment: Will try it once I get home. Thanks.

Comment: This solution is not working.
It moves my menu to the left. Anyhow, even removing the class and accepting the menu on the left, the dropdown list still appears displaced

Comment: Bump please. The issue persists