# Scrollbar added to an element when width is 100%

Tags: css, html

I'm curious why `overflow: auto;` rule adds scrollbar in this case

CSS:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

.span4 {
    width: 300px;

}

aside {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<aside class="span4">    
    <textarea cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>       
</aside>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnsW9/
If this textarea has 100% width, and without margins and paddings, how is that overflowing the container box?

Comment: Try to remove 'cols' from **textarea**.

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471850/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-value-in-a-css-property will get handy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Used to** `box-sizing`

```
textarea {
            width: 100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;

        }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/ZnsW9/5/)**

Comment: thanks, this box-sizing seems like a wonderful thing, I just can't beleive that still it can't be used in firefox without -moz- prefix

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbar is added because of border. Add `border: none;` rule to textarea:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnsW9/1/)