# What is the meaning of 'auto' value in 'left' property of css?

Tags: css

What is the meaning of "auto" value of a "left" CSS property? What happens when value of a "left" property is set to auto?

Comment: Inspired from post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471850/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-value-in-a-css-property . However, it did mention that behavior of "auto" depends upon the property it is assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `left` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left):

> `auto` specifies that:
>
> - for *absolutely positioned elements*, the position of the element is based on the `right` property, while `width: auto` is treated as a width based on the content; or if `right` is also auto, the element is positioned where it should horizontally be positioned if it were a static element.
> - for *relatively positioned elements*, the distance of the element from its normal position is based on the `right` property; or if `right` is also `auto`, the element is not moved horizontally at all.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-playground-mr4p6 - react fiddle if you wish to play around

Comment: what happens if the right property is not mentioned? left: auto and position: relative

Comment: @MansiManhas *what happens if the right property is not mentioned?* --> it means that right is also auto. You should note that auto is the default value

Comment: also found out that left + position: relative will give it a NUDGE. reference - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/left/

Answer (score 3):

Here you go [CSS: Left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)

Excerpt from the official Docs.

> **Specifies that**:
>
> **for absolutely positioned elements**, the position of the element is
>   based on the right property, while width: auto is treated as a width
>   based on the content; or if right is also auto, the element is
>   positioned where it should horizontally be positioned if it were a
>   static element.
>
> **for relatively positioned elements**, the distance of the element from
>   its normal position is based on the right property; or if right is
>   also auto, the element is not moved horizontally at all.